# Scan for Arduino peripheral by service in xcode

Tags: xcode, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

When I scan for   `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)`
 it shows up with my device        `<CBPeripheral: 0x2801b4be0, identifier = 7FD5C9DC-FD5E-6C75-5565-24DAE324B75F, name = MyESP32, state = disconnected>` 
but when I change it to the UUID I get no results

```
#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"
```

```
let ble_iotCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b")

centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ble_iotCBUUID])
```

no results

Comment: Are you certain that that uuid is being advertised?  A peripheral may only advertise a subset of the services it has

Comment: If `ble_iotCBUUID` value doesn't appear in the advertisement data of the `centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)`, it won't work.